# Fallback jQuery Reference when Google APIs inaccessible

Tags: feature-request

Stack Exchange relies on jQuery to provide some essential functionalities, such as Log In.

Currently, the reference is to Google APIs.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Although the *availability* of Google APIs is high, the *accessibility* may vary between different areas in the world.

I suggest add a secondary reference, such as [the reference from Microsoft](http://www.asp.net/ajax/cdn), when Google APIs is not accessible.

<sub>The issue turns out to be more severe. If I want to log in to Stack Exchange, I have to go to my office.</sub>